# Apply array order by only moving

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I want to reorder an array of distinct elements to look like a second array, but only using move operations.

Example:

```
Index  0 1 2 3 4
Array  e b a c d
Order  a b c d e
```

Moving operations (insert at target index):

```
original e b a c d
0→4      b a c d e
1→0      a b c d e
```

I would like to minimize the amount of moving operations and get a list of the operations (from/to index) as a result.

My background is that I fetch and sort a list of IDs from a server using javascript. However, I can only update the sorting by single-element "move to index" commands to their API.

Solution 1:
a) use the ordered array and insert all elements at the end 
b) or at position 0 in reverse order. 
That would require N operations for N elements, though, even for the best case.

Solution 2:
Iterate the ordered array and move elements into ordered position.
Furthermore, the element previously there is move to its desired position.
The latter helps if two letters are swapped, as in `e b c d a`.
While that reduces the best case scenario to 0 moves, most random cases require >N operations for N elements.

Code example for Solution 2:

```js
function arraymove(arr, fromIndex, toIndex) {
    var element = arr[fromIndex];
    arr.splice(fromIndex, 1);
    arr.splice(toIndex, 0, element);
}

function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
         var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
         var temp = array[i];
         array[i] = array[j];
         array[j] = temp;
    }
}

let newOrder = [...Array(20).keys()];
let oldOrder = [...newOrder];
//oldOrder.reverse() //reverse case
shuffleArray(oldOrder); //random case
//arraymove(oldOrder, 0, 99); //end to beginning case

let checkOrder = [...oldOrder];
let moveOrder = [];
for (ind = newOrder.length - 1; ind >= 0; --ind) {
    let el = newOrder[ind];
    if (checkOrder[ind] != el) {
         let oldind = checkOrder.indexOf(el);
         let altel = checkOrder[ind];
         arraymove(checkOrder, oldind, ind);
         moveOrder.push({ el: el, ind: ind, old: oldind });
         let altind = checkOrder.indexOf(altel);

         if (newOrder[newOrder] != altel) {
              let newind = newOrder.indexOf(altel);
              arraymove(checkOrder, altind, newind);
              moveOrder.push({ el: altel, ind: newind, old: altind });
         }
    }
}
document.write("oldOrder: ", oldOrder.join(" "),"<br> Moves: ", moveOrder.length);
```

Is there a better solution, or perhaps an already established algorithm I didn't find?
The example from above is sadly not found by Solution 2.

Comment: Are the elements of the array distinct, or can there be duplicates?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you can't do better than O(n).

Comment: @user1984 Thank you for your opinion. I also tried out a recursive approach or sorting the moves by moving distance, but with >20 elements all approaches became >n.

Comment: @user3386109 The elements are distinct.

Comment: I'm not sure big-O notation is going to be a useful metric here, where it seems like the cost of the API calls far outweighs the cost of the actual sorting. As for the algorithm, [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) seems like a good fit.

Comment: I'd start by finding the [longest increasing subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence). For example, if the original string is "ibecdgahjf", the longest increasing subsequence is "bcdghj", and the only letters that need to be moved are "aefi". When moving a letter, the only requirement is that the length of the subsequence increases. So for example, when moving the "a", you can insert it before the "i", or before the "b". Either place is fine since both increase the subsequence length.